# How to start Window Mobile programme?

Tags: wifi, windows-mobile, network-scan

I am new in Window Mobile Programming. I have to make to scan Wifi networks and join to the network using Window Mobile 6.5 Professional device, CE OS 5.2. But I do not know how to start it.

Please give me tips to start it. What language and tool is better? Where is the helpful documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Visual Studio and the Windows Mobile SDK.
As for languages, I recommend C++. You can use C#, but for the project you described, you will end up invoking the native C functions anyway.

The functions you need are in the [Zero Config API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916566.aspx).

A good resource for beginning Windows Mobile programming is the [30 days of windows mobile](http://windowsmobileapps.codeplex.com/) series.